# Insert XML data into multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I have a XML like below :

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <AccountInfo>
      <AccountNumber>1234567</AccountNumber>
      <AccountType>Test</AccountType>
    </AccountInfo>
    <DocumentType>Test Doc</DocumentType>
    <Date>12/01/2020</Date>
    <Description>Test Description</Description>
    <ImageFileType>pdf</ImageFileType>
    <ImageFileName>321.PDF</ImageFileName>    
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <FieldName>docDescription</FieldName>
      <FieldValue>ABC XYZ</FieldValue>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <FieldName>Creation Date</FieldName>
      <FieldValue>12/01/2020</FieldValue>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <FieldName>Department Code</FieldName>
      <FieldValue>63</FieldValue>
    </AdditionalInfo>    
    <AdditionalInfo>
      <FieldName>ID No</FieldName>
      <FieldValue>3214567</FieldValue>
    </AdditionalInfo>
  </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

I want to insert this XML data into 3 tables `EmployeeInfo`, `AccountInfo` and `AdditionalInfo` with schema like this:

```
EmployeeInfo 
(
    EmployeeNumber Int Identity(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    DocumentType varchar(500) NULL, 
    [Description] varchar(500) NULL,  
    ImageFileName varchar(500) NULL,
    ImageFileType varchar(500) NULL,
    [Date] varchar(500) NULL
);

AccountInfo 
(
    EmployeeNumber int NOT NULL,
    AccountNumber varchar(500) NULL, 
    AccountType varchar(500) NULL
);

AdditionalInfo 
(
    EmployeeNumber int NOT NULL, 
    FieldName varchar(500) NULL, 
    FieldValue varchar(500) NULL
);
```

`EmployeeNumber` column is used for linking `AccountInfo` and `AdditionalInfo` table with `EmployeeInfo`.

`AccountInfo` table will get below node:

```
<AccountInfo>
    <AccountNumber>1234567</AccountNumber>
    <AccountType>Test</AccountType>
</AccountInfo>
```

The `AdditionalInfo` table will get these XML nodes:

```
<AdditionalInfo>
    <FieldName>docDescription</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>ABC XYZ</FieldValue>
</AdditionalInfo>
<AdditionalInfo>
    <FieldName>Creation Date</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>12/01/2020</FieldValue>
</AdditionalInfo>
<AdditionalInfo>
    <FieldName>Department Code</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>63</FieldValue>
</AdditionalInfo>    
<AdditionalInfo>
    <FieldName>ID No</FieldName>
    <FieldValue>3214567</FieldValue>
</AdditionalInfo>
```

Rest xml node are inserted into `EmployeeInfo`.

I tried with the query shown here. I'm able to get xml data and insert it into main table `EmployeeInfo`, but not able to link `AdditionalInfo` and `AccountInfo` with identity generated in `EmployeeInfo` table.

**Note**: I have multiple employee nodes in the xml.

```
DECLARE @EmpNumber int
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = X FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Test\Sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS EmpInfo(X)
DECLARE @hdoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo (DocumentType, [Description], ImageFileName, ImageFileType, [Date])
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Employees/Employee', 2)
WITH ( DocumentType varchar(500), [Description] varchar(500), ImageFileName varchar(500), ImageFileType varchar(500), [Date] varchar(500))

SELECT @EmpNumber=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO AccountInfo ([EmployeeNumber],[AccountNumber], [AccountType])
    SELECT @EmpNumber, * 
    FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Employees/Employee/AccountInfo', 2)
    WITH (AccountNumber varchar(500), AccountType varchar(500))

INSERT INTO AdditionalInfo ([EmployeeNumber],[FieldName], [FieldValue])
    SELECT @EmpNumber, * 
    FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Employees/Employee/AdditionalInfo', 2)
    WITH (
       FieldName varchar(5000), FieldValue varchar(5000)
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Can someone help me out in this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using those old system procedures? SQL Server has supported XQuery since *at least* 2005.

Comment: This is one of the many ways that I'm trying to achieve.  I have used nodes() and value() in another approach as mentioned in below comment. The main issue is that I'm not able to figure out how to insert identity generated (in EmployeeInfo for each row) into AccountInfo & AccountInfo. My XML has many Employee nodes. I'm getting the last inserted identity with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), which is not correct.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example how to do it.

Two tables, *state* as a parent, and *city* as a child, with one-to-many relationship. Primary keys are `IDENTITY` based.

`INSERT` into a parent table generates new `IDENTITY` values that are captured and stored in a table variable, and later used to INSERT into a child table to preserve foreign key constraint.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #city;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #state;

-- parent table
CREATE TABLE #state  (
   stateID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   stateName VARCHAR(30), 
   abbr CHAR(2), 
   capital VARCHAR(30)
);
-- child table (1-to-many)
CREATE TABLE #city (
   cityID INT IDENTITY, 
   stateID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #state(stateID), 
   city VARCHAR(30), 
   [population] INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (cityID, stateID, city)
);
-- mapping table to preserve IDENTITY ids
DECLARE @idmapping TABLE (GeneratedID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NaturalID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<root>
   <state>
      <StateName>Florida</StateName>
      <Abbr>FL</Abbr>
      <Capital>Tallahassee</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Miami</city>
            <population>470194</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Orlando</city>
            <population>285713</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
   <state>
      <StateName>Texas</StateName>
      <Abbr>TX</Abbr>
      <Capital>Austin</Capital>
      <cities>
         <city>
            <city>Houston</city>
            <population>2100263</population>
         </city>
         <city>
            <city>Dallas</city>
            <population>5560892</population>
         </city>
      </cities>
   </state>
</root>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT stateName   = p.value('(StateName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           abbr         = p.value('(Abbr/text())[1]', 'CHAR(2)'),
           capital      = p.value('(Capital/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/state') AS t(p)
 )
 MERGE #state AS o
 USING rs ON 1 = 0
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(stateName, abbr, capital)  
       VALUES(rs.stateName, rs.Abbr, rs.Capital)
 OUTPUT inserted.stateID, rs.stateName 
   INTO @idmapping (GeneratedID, NaturalID);

;WITH Details AS 
(
    SELECT NaturalID   = p.value('(StateName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           city         = c.value('(city/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'),
           [population]   = c.value('(population/text())[1]', 'INT')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/state') AS A(p)   -- parent
      CROSS APPLY A.p.nodes('cities/city') AS B(c) -- child
) 
INSERT #city (stateID, city, [Population])
SELECT m.GeneratedID, d.city, d.[Population]
FROM   Details AS d
   INNER JOIN @idmapping AS m ON d.NaturalID = m.NaturalID;

-- test
SELECT * FROM #state;
SELECT * FROM @idmapping;
SELECT * FROM #city;
```

Comment: I don't see any node/column that fit as NaturalID in my case.

Comment: Your candidates for it: DocumentType , [Description],  ImageFileName, ImageFileType. So just pick one of them, or combination of two/three of them

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using sp_xml_preparedocument, OPENXML and sp_xml_removedocument because they are inefficient, often cause resource leakage when sp_xml_removedocument is forgotten, and encourage RBAR-like constructs in what's supposed to be a set-based RDBMS.

Prefer to use [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) where possible, such as with the following...

```sql
insert dbo.EmployeeInfo (DocumentType, [Description], ImageFileName, ImageFileType, [Date])
  select
    Employee.value('(DocumentType/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    Employee.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    Employee.value('(ImageFileName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    Employee.value('(ImageFileType/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    Employee.value('(Date/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
  from @xml.nodes('/Employees/Employee') root(Employee);

declare @EmpNumber int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

insert dbo.AccountInfo ([EmployeeNumber], [AccountNumber], [AccountType])
  select
    @EmpNumber,
    AccountInfo.value('(AccountNumber/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    AccountInfo.value('(AccountType/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
  from @xml.nodes('/Employees/Employee/AccountInfo') root(AccountInfo);

insert dbo.AdditionalInfo ([EmployeeNumber], [FieldName], [FieldValue])
  select
    @EmpNumber,
    AdditionalInfo.value('(FieldName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
    AdditionalInfo.value('(FieldValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
  from @xml.nodes('/Employees/Employee/AdditionalInfo') root(AdditionalInfo);
```

Comment: Main problem is that I'm not able to get the identity value generated in EmployeeInfo  for each row and insert it into AccountInfo & AccountInfo for corresponding Employee node.  I'm having multiple Employee nodes.

Comment: If you need to get the `IDENTITY` value of multiple rows, use the `OUTPUT` clause, @JDA .